# Eclipse Maven Build: Missing requirement with own project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho

I am trying to make a Maven Build using Tycho of my Eclipse RCP 3 Product. 
This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin</groupId>
   <artifactId>de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.0.qualifier</version>
   <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
   <repositories>
        <repository>
           <id>eclipse-oxygen</id>
           <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen</url>
           <layout>p2</layout>
        </repository>
   </repositories>
   <properties>
        <tycho-version>1.0.0</tycho-version>
   </properties>
   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <dependency-resolution>
                         <extraRequirements>
                            <requirement>
                               <type>eclipse-feature</type>
                               <id>de.dspace.qpm.admintool.auxiliary</id>
                               <versionRange>1.2.0 qualifier</versionRange>
                            </requirement>
                         </extraRequirements>
                  </dependency-resolution>
                </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

The pom.xml is in my core project. The core depends on two other Eclipse Projects (These are not Eclipse Products), namely "interfaces" and "auxiliary". I don't know how to add these to my pom.xml so that the Maven build works. I tried it via the "dependency-resolution"-tag but it doesn't work. You can see in the Log-file:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00)
Maven home: C:\Users\PhilipF\git8\QPM_AdminTool\de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin\EMBEDDED
Java version: 1.8.0_141, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_141
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.util.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution.scope < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.helpers.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from EMBEDDED\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\PhilipF\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from EMBEDDED\conf\toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from C:\Users\PhilipF\.m2\toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Users\PhilipF\.m2\repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\PhilipF\.m2\repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=2, ConflictMarker.markTime=0, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=93, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=1, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=42, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=8, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=92, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=426, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=13}
[DEBUG] org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:jar:1.0.0:
[DEBUG]    org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-core:jar:1.0.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:jar:3.0:runtime
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.aether:aether-impl:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]             org.sonatype.aether:aether-spi:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.aether:aether-api:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.aether:aether-util:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:jar:1.4.2:compile
[DEBUG]             org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:1.4.2:compile
[DEBUG]                org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:noaop:2.1.7:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.14:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.2.3:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]             org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.7:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:2.9.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:2.4.1:compile
[DEBUG]             commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.9:compile
[DEBUG]       org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state:jar:1.0.200.v20160504-1419:compile
[DEBUG]       org.eclipse.tycho:sisu-equinox-embedder:jar:1.0.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.osgi:jar:3.11.2.v20161107-1947:compile
[DEBUG]          org.eclipse.tycho:sisu-equinox-api:jar:1.0.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-metadata-model:jar:1.0.0:compile
[DEBUG]          de.pdark:decentxml:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]       org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-embedder-api:jar:1.0.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.tycho.embedder.shared:jar:1.0.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.tycho.core.shared:jar:1.0.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-compat:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:1.0-beta-6:compile
[DEBUG]    org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-facade:jar:1.0.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:compile
[DEBUG]       org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.shared:jar:1.0.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.tycho.p2.tools.shared:jar:1.0.0:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm extension>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:1.0.0
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm extension>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:1.0.0
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm extension>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:1.0.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:jar:1.0.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-core:jar:1.0.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.aether:aether-util:jar:1.7
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:1.4.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:noaop:2.1.7
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.14
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.7
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.7
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:2.9.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:2.4.1
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.9
[DEBUG]   Included: org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state:jar:1.0.200.v20160504-1419
[DEBUG]   Included: org.eclipse.tycho:sisu-equinox-embedder:jar:1.0.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.osgi:jar:3.11.2.v20161107-1947
[DEBUG]   Included: org.eclipse.tycho:sisu-equinox-api:jar:1.0.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-metadata-model:jar:1.0.0
[DEBUG]   Included: de.pdark:decentxml:jar:1.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-embedder-api:jar:1.0.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.tycho.embedder.shared:jar:1.0.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.tycho.core.shared:jar:1.0.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-facade:jar:1.0.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.shared:jar:1.0.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.tycho.p2.tools.shared:jar:1.0.0
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin:de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin:eclipse-plugin:1.4.0.qualifier: [ClassRealm[extension>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:1.0.0, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05]]
[DEBUG] Created new class realm project>de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin:de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin:1.4.0.qualifier
[DEBUG] Populating class realm project>de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin:de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin:1.4.0.qualifier
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging eclipse-plugin from ClassRealm[project>de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin:de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin:1.4.0.qualifier, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[DEBUG] org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:1.0.0 configured in MavenProject: de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin:de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin:1.4.0.qualifier @ C:\Users\PhilipF\git8\QPM_AdminTool\de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin\pom.xml
[DEBUG] org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:1.0.0 configured in MavenProject: de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin:de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin:1.4.0.qualifier @ C:\Users\PhilipF\git8\QPM_AdminTool\de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin\pom.xml
[DEBUG] org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-plugin:1.0.0 configured in MavenProject: de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin:de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin:1.4.0.qualifier @ C:\Users\PhilipF\git8\QPM_AdminTool\de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin\pom.xml
[WARNING] No explicit target runtime environment configuration. Build is platform dependent.
Debug options:
    file:/C:/Users/PhilipF/git8/QPM_AdminTool/de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin/.options not found
Time to load bundles: 368
[DEBUG] Clearing proxy settings in OSGi runtime
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=0, ConflictMarker.markTime=1, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=102, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=46, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=2, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=101, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=111, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=3}
[DEBUG] org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-plugin:jar:1.0.0:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:jar:1.4.2:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:1.4.2:compile
[DEBUG]             org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:noaop:2.1.7:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:jar:3.0:runtime
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.aether:aether-impl:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.aether:aether-spi:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.aether:aether-api:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.aether:aether-util:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.14:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.7:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.2.3:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]    org.eclipse.tycho:sisu-equinox-launching:jar:1.0.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-core:jar:1.0.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:2.9.1:compile
[DEBUG]             org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:2.4.1:compile
[DEBUG]                commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile
[DEBUG]             org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.9:compile
[DEBUG]          org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state:jar:1.0.200.v20160504-1419:compile
[DEBUG]          org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-metadata-model:jar:1.0.0:compile
[DEBUG]             de.pdark:decentxml:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]          org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-embedder-api:jar:1.0.0:compile
[DEBUG]             org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.tycho.embedder.shared:jar:1.0.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.tycho.core.shared:jar:1.0.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-compat:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]             org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:1.0-beta-6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.eclipse.tycho:sisu-equinox-api:jar:1.0.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.2:compile
[DEBUG]    org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-facade:jar:1.0.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.eclipse.tycho:sisu-equinox-embedder:jar:1.0.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.osgi:jar:3.11.2.v20161107-1947:compile
[DEBUG]       org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.shared:jar:1.0.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.tycho.p2.tools.shared:jar:1.0.0:compile
[DEBUG]    org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-artifactcomparator:jar:1.0.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:jar:5.0.3:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-plugin:1.0.0
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-plugin:1.0.0
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < project>de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin:de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin:1.4.0.qualifier
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-plugin:1.0.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-plugin:jar:1.0.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:1.4.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:noaop:2.1.7
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.aether:aether-util:jar:1.7
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.14
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.7
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.7
[DEBUG]   Included: org.eclipse.tycho:sisu-equinox-launching:jar:1.0.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:2.9.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:2.4.1
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.9
[DEBUG]   Included: org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state:jar:1.0.200.v20160504-1419
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-artifactcomparator:jar:1.0.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:jar:5.0.3
[INFO] Computing target platform for MavenProject: de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin:de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin:1.4.0.qualifier @ C:\Users\PhilipF\git8\QPM_AdminTool\de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin\pom.xml
[DEBUG] Added p2 repository eclipse-oxygen (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen)
[DEBUG] Using execution environment 'JavaSE-1.7' configured in Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment (first entry)
[DEBUG] Registered artifact repository org.eclipse.tycho.repository.registry.facade.RepositoryBlackboardKey(uri=file:/resolution-context-artifacts@C%253A%255CUsers%255CPhilipF%255Cgit8%255CQPM_AdminTool%255Cde.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin)
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/
[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/oxygen/
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/oxygen/
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/201706281000/
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/201706281000/
[DEBUG] Added 0 locally built units to the target platform
[INFO] Resolving dependencies of MavenProject: de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin:de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin:1.4.0.qualifier @ C:\Users\PhilipF\git8\QPM_AdminTool\de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin\pom.xml
[DEBUG] No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin 1.4.0.qualifier to bundle de.dspace.qpm.admintool.auxiliary 1.2.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin 1.4.0.qualifier to bundle de.dspace.qpm.admintool.interfaces 1.2.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin 1.4.0.qualifier to package de.dspace.qpm.admintool.auxiliary.ds 0.0.0.; Unable to satisfy dependency from de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin 1.4.0.qualifier to package de.dspace.qpm.admintool.auxiliary.test.tupel 0.0.0.; No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.]
[INFO] {osgi.os=win32, osgi.ws=win32, org.eclipse.update.install.features=true, osgi.arch=x86_64}
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin 1.4.0.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin 1.4.0.qualifier requires 'bundle de.dspace.qpm.admintool.auxiliary 1.2.0' but it could not be found
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Dependency_Resolution_Troubleshooting for help.
[ERROR] Cannot resolve dependencies of MavenProject: de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin:de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin:1.4.0.qualifier @ C:\Users\PhilipF\git8\QPM_AdminTool\de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin\pom.xml: See log for details -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.MavenExecutionException: Cannot resolve dependencies of MavenProject: de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin:de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin:1.4.0.qualifier @ C:\Users\PhilipF\git8\QPM_AdminTool\de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin\pom.xml
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:266)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.tycho.artifacts.DependencyResolutionException: Cannot resolve dependencies of MavenProject: de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin:de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin:1.4.0.qualifier @ C:\Users\PhilipF\git8\QPM_AdminTool\de.dspace.qpm.admintool.coreplugin\pom.xml
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(P2ResolverImpl.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(P2ResolverImpl.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.doResolveDependencies(P2DependencyResolver.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.resolveDependencies(P2DependencyResolver.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoResolver.resolveProject(DefaultTychoResolver.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:95)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.tycho.p2.util.resolution.ResolverException: See log for details
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.util.resolution.ProjectorResolutionStrategy.resolve(ProjectorResolutionStrategy.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.util.resolution.AbstractResolutionStrategy.resolve(AbstractResolutionStrategy.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(P2ResolverImpl.java:195)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MavenExecutionException
```

I get an error "Missing Requirement" concerning the auxiliary project. Can you tell me how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

It's the requirement that are missing.

```
<requirement>
  <type>eclipse-feature</type>
  <id>de.dspace.qpm.admintool.auxiliary</id>
  <versionRange>1.2.0 qualifier</versionRange>
</requirement>
```

You need to install the projet to your repository local or remote.

To install the projet, you just have to get the source (`de.dspace.qpm.admintool.auxiliary`) in you computer and type `mvn install`

Comment: If I delete this requirement I still get the same error. And the project sources are in my local repository. I think the error is due to the fact that the "auxiliary"-project is in the Plugins of my core Eclipse project. I don't know how to add it properly in the pom.xml